# Website Redirection from main domain(ASP.net) to Sub-domain(PHP)

Tags: php, asp.net, url, redirect, plesk

I have a website, which is created on asp.net and its URL is www.mydomain.com. I have another website which is created in PHP and hosted as www.new.mydomain.com. 
    I have a menu(LOGIN) in my PHP website which will redirect to www.mydomain.com/login.aspx.

When I change the document root, the website works fine, but the menu(LOGIN) returns with server error.

The website is hosted in pesk.

Is there any way to overcome this issue??

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 404 server not found

Answer (score 0):

If your redirect is realy to

```
www.mydomain.com/login.aspx
```

then you need to add

```
 http://
 or 
 https:// if the site runs on https.
```

That should handle the error message as the server should be found.

Comment: both my domain and sub-domain are relays on https://. I tried it with https as well as http, but same result.

Comment: I wonder why you use www.new.mydomain.com as subdomain instead of new.mydomain.com (without the www). Can you visit www.mydomain.com/login.aspx direct? Just to narrow down to problem possibilities.

Comment: I can access both www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com as well as www.mydomain.com/login.aspx and mydomain.com/login.aspx, all methods are works fine, but when I do the redirection then only the problem rises

Comment: mydomain.com website is inside "/httpdocs" and new.mydomain.com is in "/new.mydomain.com". The login.aspx is inside "httpdocs". I want to access that file from "/new.mydomain.com"

Comment: Shouldn't your link in the menu be just like www.mydomain.com/login.aspx with the https;// in front?